Can't understand why my background image doesn't display
I am trying to make the background image display on .hero, which means the image will be at the center of the page, but the image doesn't display at all. In "devtools", it shows a warning sign next to the image.
I tried to put the image on the body and eliminate the position absolute that I put in the CSS; however, it didn't affect the results. Please help. I thought the position absolute might push other elements like the .hero class, which has the background image. I also tried writing it in several ways with '' and with two dots and even with one dot.


.hero {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/100/100") center center/cover
    no-repeat;
  margin-top: 8rem;
  padding: 11.5rem 2rem 8rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
<header class="hero">
  <div class="container-heroflex">
    <div class="hero-content">
      <h1>Create your own video courses</h1>
      <p>
        dive deep into the world of creativity and learn to craft stunning
        videos that captivate your audience
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="btn">29$ Get Course</a>
    </div>
    <div class="hero-img">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt="header-course" />
    </div>
  </div>
</header>




"On devtools it shows next to the image a warning sign" and what does the error say? Is the path to the image correct?

how can I check what does the error says

background-image: should be just background: (as shorthand). The values seems in the good definition order.  If it still does not work, keep those changes, and try to additionally fix the path. (Hit F12 key (to open Dev tools), and see in Console or Network tab if there's any errors in fetching the image)

it doesn't show in the Network that there are errors its so weird

Quoting from CSS background docs

The background shorthand CSS property sets all background style properties at once, such as color, image, origin and size, or repeat method. Component properties not set in the background shorthand property value declaration are set to their default values.

Simply use the background property instead of background-image like this:


.hero {
  background: url('https://m-sarabi.ir/assets/personal-header.jpg') center center/cover no-repeat;
  margin-top: 8rem;
  padding: 11.5rem 2rem 8rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
<header class="hero">
  <div class="container-heroflex">
    <div class="hero-content">
      <h1>Create your own video courses</h1>
      <p>dive deep into the world of creativity and learn to craft stunning videos that captivate your audience
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="btn">29$ Get Course</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>




yes! thank you very much

its very weird that when I add background-image it doesnt show but with only background value it does show..

It's because background-image is intended to accept an image (as the name implies), not the full background short-hand

@shirshamay It is because background is shorthand for all background style properties. You were using background-image and yet setting multiple background properties for it, as shown in @foysal-kabir-shimul's answer.

You need to separate background-image the position, size, and repeat in different line.
.hero {
        background-image: url('../images/header-background.png');
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin-top: 8rem;
        padding: 11.5rem 2rem 8rem;
        position: relative;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }


Not necessarily. The simplest would be to use background: (instead of background-image:) as shorthand for all the available values (which seem in the right order BTW) - but well spotted!

No this is no the problem, It can be a shorthand

You can try using this code:
.hero {
background: url('../images/header-background.jpg') center center / cover no-repeat;
margin-top: 8rem;
padding: 11.5rem 2rem 8rem;
position: relative;
overflow-x: hidden;

}
I hope this helps you.
